# What is "Blocking Others"

Tags: phabricator

I'm very new to phabricator, and I do not understand the term "Blocking Others" as it is used in the 'Active Revisions' dashboard.  There are several bugs going back to (at least) Oct 2103 addressing this (
https://secure.phabricator.com/T1279#42118,
https://secure.phabricator.com/T4144, https://secure.phabricator.com/T10031), but I remain confused.

If I accept a revision, how can I configure Phabricator to place that revision in a non-obtrusive location until such time as it has changed and requires my attention again?  I do not understand why all of the revisions that appear under the top heading "Blocking Others" are revisions on which I am the last person to take action and clearly do not require my attention.  My current work flow is to completely ignore that section.  I would like it to go away, but perhaps there is something I should understand that would make that section useful rather than annoying.

Comment: Are you also using Blocking Reviewers? Most installs do not, and "Blocking Others" is a direct correlation to what you need to review.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Blocking Reviewers set up, the "Blocking Others" section can be confusing (since it's not you probably blocking the user). The item is blocked though. There are some upstream tasks on sorting this out better, see https://secure.phabricator.com/T4144.